# Query using AJAX. PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm fairly new at using AJAX and I can't seem to understand what I am doing wrong. I'm trying to query to my db using AJAX, I can already pass the data to javascript but it doesn't continue to the $.ajax({}) part.

Here is my AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mamamo(projectID, taskID, requestID) {
    //alert(projectID + " " + taskID + " " + requestID);
    var projectID = projectID;
    var taskID = taskID;
    var requestID = requestID;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/request/view_request",
        data:{'projectID':projectID, 'taskID':taskID, 'requestID':requestID},
        success:function(data) {
            //$('#resultdiv').html(data);
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
};
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    function view_request(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('users/login');
    }       

    $projectID = $this->input->post('projectID');
    $taskID = $this->input->post('taskID');
    $requestID = $this->input->post('requestID');

    $data['title'] = '';
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $data['curr_request'] = $this->request->get_current_request($requestID);
    mysqli_next_result($CI->db->conn_id);
    $data['request_history'] = $this->request->get_request_history($requestID, $projectID, $taskID);
    mysqli_next_result($CI->db->conn_id);
    $data['translations'] = $this->translation->get_translation($projectID, $taskID);
    mysqli_next_result($CI->db->conn_id);
    $data['translation_changes'] = $this->translation->get_translation_change($projectID, $taskID);

    mysqli_next_result($CI->db->conn_id);
    //history of selected translation
    $data['request_history'] = $this->request->get_request_history($requestID, $projectID, $taskID);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the `view_request()` method on the `view_request.php` page - or have you just defined it?

Comment: return a valid json then iterate the response in your success block

Comment: where are you calling this `mamamo()` function in jquery?

Comment: @GROVER. I'm calling it the function from that controller yes.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I'm calling it in my php page using onclick. I actually got the function working now but I still can't get the array data (e.g. I want to get $data[curr_request])...

Comment: @JohnJoshuaCruzMascareñas what error do you see in console ? when you do `console.log(data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

```
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?php echo site_url('request/view_request'); ?>/" + projectID + "/" + taskID + "/" + requestID,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: json,
            success:function(data) {
               //code here
            }
```

I change the 'URL:' and used the data in the url to pass to th controller. Then decoded it to be passed back to my php page.

Thanks for all your help!